# are this way really good in c# for passing parameter

Tags: c#

In my apps i need a List to pass as a parameter.

i write it

```
List<stuff.Inventory> inv = new List<stuff.Inventory>();
inv.Add(stuff.Inventory.NotAvailable);
inv.Add(stuff.Inventory.None);
inv.Add(stuff.Inventory.Coming);

if (stuff.isStuffinInv(inv, prodID))
{
    // ...
}
```

are my way is right or need any new way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, aside from naming conventions and indentation, it looks okay.

With C# 3 you can use a collection initializer, like this:

```
List<Inventory> inventory = new List<Inventory>
{
    Inventory.NotAvailable, Inventory.None, Inventory.Coming
};
if (stuff.isStuffInInv(inventory, prodID))
...
```

That's a generally more readable approach, IMO.

Comment: Your naming of `inventory` is inconsistent - you pass `inv` to the function. Darn copy-paste errors. =]

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of it Inventory appears to be an emum. Have you considered using the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<stuff.Inventory> inv = new List<stuff.Inventory>()
{
   stuff.Inventory.NotAvailable, 
   stuff.Inventory.None, 
   stuff.Inventory.Coming
};
```

From what you've described though, would an enum be more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly wrong with that code, but you might want to consider using LINQ to query your list, rather than having your isStuffInInv method.

```
if (inv.Any(x => x._?_ == prodID));
```

Comment: I would have to disagree here. IsStuffInInv is far more readable than your LINQ query. Using a LINQ query under the hood would be a better idea, however for all you know IsStuffInInv is already doing this...

Comment: @ mark i not want to play with linq. i just need a simple c# method who i already get

Comment: @4thpage: You shouldn't write off Mark's suggestion of using LINQ. I was simply questioning the fact he was saying you should directly replace your `IsStuffInInv` method. IMO your internal workings of that method should probably be doing some form of LINQ query (unless you have a faster more optimized solution).

Comment: ok @ james , mark i could be wrong so please tell me in detailed. how i can use it in my code. if i can used it that Sorry for first comment. don't worry for last comment just tell me how i can use it

Comment: @4thpage: I would recommend you created a separate question for this. Or even better, have a look on the site for already asked questions similar to this.